# Can we use main, printf,scanf for naming identifiers?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
  int main=5;
  printf("%d",main);
  return 0;
}
```

In this case there is no error and the gcc compiler prints 5. But if I write

```
 int main()
    {
        int printf=5;
        printf("%d",printf);
        return 0;
    }
```

the compiler shows an error..why ?

Comment: AFAIk the second example should work in C++ if you use the `::` operator for the printf call, like: `::printf("%d",printf);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first code snippet, you declare a local variable *main*, which is in the **local** scope, so it has no effect on the **global** scope (where the **main()** function is declared)

In the second code snippet, you declare "printf" in global scope, where the **printf()** function lives, so you have a conflict.

Comment: It wasn't me that downvoted you, but on the assumption the printf lines should be inside main, your explanation is wrong.  The error occurs because he is trying to treat an int named printf (which shadows the function declaration) as a function.

Answer (score 9):

In your 1st example you "hide" the `main` function, replacing it with an `int` object.

In your 2nd example you "hide" the `printf` function, replacing it with an `int` object.
Trying to call an `int` is illegal.

```
5("foo"); /* illegal to call "function" 5 */
```

Answer (score 2):

In the second example, you have declared a local variable of type 'int' called 'printf'. This will take precedence over the global function of the same name. So the error is that the name 'printf' refers to an int, not a function.

In your first example, you override the global function name 'main' with a local variable called 'main'. If you had not done that, you would in fact be able to call the 'main' function from within the main function, and that would have worked. With your variable declaration, that is no longer possible as the local variable declaration takes precedence - but it's still perfectly usable in the variable form.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use function names as variable names, ever, for any reason.

Comment: "Yes, but you shouldn't" would be an answer. What you have there is just advice. (BTW, I didn't DV)

Comment: Bloody good advice though.  I boggled when I saw the question.  I think this answer is more useful to the OP than the actual answer.

Comment: It's very difficult advice to follow, since if you include headers from third parties, you don't necessarily know all the names of all the functions that are (or ever will be) declared in that header. C development relies on programmers using naming conventions, but it doesn't rely on them so strongly that it breaks if you unwittingly shadow a name (since if it's unwitting, you won't also use the name to reference the function, as Parixit does in the example code, because you don't realise it's a function). You could have problems if the header uses the function name in macros, though.